# Кто работал с IPSerial.dll производства Moxa Nport

Tags: c#

Необходимо по ip подключаться к оборудованию, что то писать в порт и получать данные. Кто работал отзовитесь. Так то есть пример сразу в Нпорт администраторе, но он не полный. Вот оригинальная [программа](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualfile.aspx?id=16175716)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### саппорт такое написал

Мы правильно поняли, что речь идёт об устройстве NPort 5110?
Если честно, мы в своих проектах не используем библиотеку ipserial. С NPort можно легко работать и без нее. Для этого:
1. Переведите NPort в режим TCP Server;
2. Установите TCP-соединение с NPort (по умолчанию Data Port = TCP:4001)
3. Посылайте в TCP-сокет данные, они в неизменном виде выйдут в COM-порт;
4. Данные, которые NPort будет принимать по последовательному интерфейсу, он будет передавать в этот же TCP-сокет.

Команцев Александр | ООО "Ниеншанц-Автоматика",

ну а тут код тсп клиента

```
    #region main
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        Connect("10.81.0.102", "#10", 4001);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          textBox1.Text =  ex.ToString();
        }

    }
    #endregion

    #region client
    static void Connect(String server, String message, Int32 port )
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a TcpClient.
            // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
            // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
            // combination.
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

            // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
           // Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            Byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
            //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

           MessageBox.Show("Sent: " +  message);

            // Receive the TcpServer.response.

            // Buffer to store the response bytes.
            data = new Byte[256];

            // String to store the response ASCII representation.
            String responseData = String.Empty;

            // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            MessageBox.Show("Received: {0}"+ responseData);

            // Close everything.
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("ArgumentNullException: {0}"+ e.ToString());
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SocketException: {0}"+ e.ToString());
        }

        MessageBox.Show("\n Press Enter to continue...");

    }
    #endregion
```